# AWS will be sponsoring Server Fault

Tags: discussion

We're thrilled to announce that [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) will be sponsoring Server Fault starting on **July 18 through December 31**. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what that means.

#### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be found on the right side of the header at the top of the site similar to what you see below.

[image]

### What else changes?

Not a thing! Borrowing from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who could be interested in their products know about them in a non-intrusive way.

### What if I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's all. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Server Fault successful.

Comment: Was there any feedback from Octopus Deploy you can share about their sponsorship ?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you cooperate with Amazon, a company that has
[a](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2020/feb/05/amazon-workers-protest-unsafe-grueling-conditions-warehouse)
[very](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/16/technology/inside-amazon-wrestling-big-ideas-in-a-bruising-workplace.html)
[long](https://www.ft.com/content/ed6a985c-70bd-11e2-85d0-00144feab49a?mhq5j=e1)
[and](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/11/amazon-accused-of-intolerable-conditions-at-scottish-warehouse)
[well](https://www.businessinsider.de/gruenderszene/allgemein/ard-amazon-leiharbeiter/)
[known](https://www.vox.com/recode/2020/9/24/21455196/amazon-employees-listservs-minorities-underrepresented-groups-worker-dissent-unionizationo)
[history](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2019/03/amazon-workers-compensation-amcare-clinic-warehouse/)
[for](https://sk.sagepub.com/cases/addressing-poor-working-conditions-amazon-challenges-covid-19)
[its](https://journals.aom.org/doi/abs/10.5465/AMBPP.2019.11833abstract)
[terrible](https://www.workerslaw.com/posts/amazon-workplace-conditions/)
[working](https://www.boredpanda.com/amazon-employees-bad-working-conditions/)
[conditions](https://documentaryheaven.com/amazon-truth-behind-click/)
[for](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/1119-megacorp-89680740/)
[its](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=amazon%20working%20conditions)
[workers<sup>1</sup>](https://www.ethicalconsumer.org/company-profile/amazoncom-inc)?

Do not Stack Exchange have any supplier ethics policy or similar guidelines?

I get that AWS probably is not the worst place to work. But it is still owned by and supports Amazon.

If you were on vacation in Italia, would you eat at a pizza restaurant owned by the mafia? Let's assume that the pizza restaurant is fully legal, pays all its taxes and does nothing wrong. If you eat there you are still financing criminals and undermining safety and democracy.

What is most important for Stack Exchange, ethics or profit?

---

<sup>1</sup> Or *"contractor"*/*"retailer"*/[whatever euphemism Amazon fancies using](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/amazon-germany-strike_n_5868532).

Comment: The 'cooperate' because they get paid.